# x86 Assembly "Unable to Load Program" in DOSbox

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-emulation

I am creating my first x86 assembly program. I am using VS Code as my editor and using Insight as my debugger coupled with DOSBox as my emulator.

As a start I have created a `.asm` program to change to colour of the screen:

```
   global _start

    section .text

_start:
    call set_colour
    ret 16

set_colour:
    mov ah, 06h         ; scroll up function
    xor al, al          ; clear entire screen
    xor cx, cx          ; upper left corner
    mov dx, 184fh       ; lower right corner
    mov bh, 1eh         ; yellow on blue
    int 10h
    ret
```

When I try convert this `.asm` file to a `.o` file DOSBox returns an error saying it cannot load the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It needs to be compiled to an .exe file, not just down to a .o object file.

Comment: @WillWalsh as far as I understand it needs to get converted to an `.o` object before it gets converted to an `.exe` file? When I try converting to `.o` I get the error..?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. So, to clarify, you are using a compiler within DOSBox to compile from .asm to .o and DOSBox returns an error saying it cannot load the file or the compiler returns an error saying it cannot load the file?

Comment: @WillWalsh That is correct.. I am trying to use Insight to compile the `.asm` within DOSBox. Namely, I am using the command: `insight -f win32 q2.asm -o q2.o`

Comment: While DOSBox emulates a 32-bit CPU, DOS runs in 16-bit real mode, without tools like DOS4gw, used in some DOS Games, such as Doom. I think the `-f win32` command line option may be to blame for this error.

Comment: @WillWalsh you are correct, sir. Thanks. If you add this as the answer I can mark this question as closed.

Comment: Awesome. Happy to have helped. Enjoy your coding journey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While DOSBox emulates a 32-bit CPU, DOS itself runs in 16-bit real mode, without tools like DOS4gw, used in some DOS Games, such as Doom.

I think the `-f win32` command line option is to blame for this error.